# CSS 6 column setup issues

Tags: html, css

How would I take this:

```
<div>
 <p class="center">
    {foreach key=num item=listtld from=$tldslist}
      <div class="{if ($num+1) % 3 == 1}column-left{elseif ($num+1) % 3 == 2}column-center{elseif ($num+1) % 3 == 0}column-right{/if}">
          <input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="{$listtld}"{if in_array($listtld,$tlds)} checked{/if}>
          {$listtld}
          {if $num % 5 == 0}
          {/if}
      </div>
   {/foreach}
</p>
```

```
.column-left{ float: left; width: 33%; }
.column-right{ float: right; width: 33%; }
.column-center{ display: inline-block; width: 33%; }
```

And make it 6 columns? Thanks, I'm really new at this.

Comment: It looks like this is a template script for a 3-column design.  Do you have access to the CSS files?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, can we have your code on Jsfiddle so we can perhaps play around. A trick would be to make a table separator inside each of those 33.33% columns to give you a 2-col effect.

Answer (score 1):

Rework your html a bit to clean it up:

```
<div class="center">
    <!-- Removed the <p> tag - it contains <div> elements, which don't belong within <p> elements -->
    {foreach key=num item=listtld from=$tldslist}
      <!-- Removed the class if / else conditions.  Simplify to one class - column -->
      <div class="column">
          <input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="{$listtld}"{if in_array($listtld,$tlds)} checked{/if}>
          {$listtld}
          {if $num % 5 == 0}
          {/if}
      </div>
   {/foreach}
</div>
```

Note, I simplified your classes as well.  Not necessary to achieve what you want.  Simple is better!

CSS:

```
div.column {
    width: 16%;                     /* approximately 1/6 */
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;                        /* ie-7 hack for inline block to work */
    *display: inline;               /* ie-7 hack for inline-block to work */
    border: 1px solid red;          /* temporary - to clearly show the box */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* to prevent padding issues if you add padding */
    margin: 0;                      /* to ensure the right width */
    vertical-align: top;            /* to line them up evenly across the top */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N39VM/

Comment: thank you so much for the great work, however the columns are centered in the screen but the boxes are a little all over and wanted them to be consecutive heres an image of what it looks like, http://s2.postimg.org/o9uqnpk21/Untitled_2.jpg How would  I go about fixing this? Thanks

Comment: The one thing to be watch out for is the extra white space that can appear between two inline-block elements, which can add just enough width to the row to force an element to wrap (unexpectedly) onto a second row.  The way to avoid this is to keep all the inline-block elements as a single line within the source code.  Finally, if you use higher precision for the width (16.666666 for example), you will get a better fit (closer to 100%) to the overall width of the parent container.

Comment: @user3646836 - leave text-align center on the *parent*, and add text-align left to the `div.column`, and that will clean up the contents to be lined up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using floats.

For the CSS:

```
div.column {
    width: 16.66666666666666666666%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px dotted gray;        /* temporary - to clearly show the box */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

and the HTML would look something like:

```
<div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="1" />Label Text</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="1" />Label Text</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="1" />Label Text</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="1" />Label Text</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="1" />Label Text</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="1" />Label Text</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="1" />Label Text</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="1" />Label Text</div>    
</div>
```

If you have more than 6 input fields, then the second set of 6 elements will start on a second row, which may be a good option.

The `box-sizing` property is useful if you want to add borders and padding.

The `width` value should be given enough precision to make sure that the columns do
fill up the width.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/WpuFL/

Note: I am just showing how the CSS could work.  You still need to implement it within the
template scripting code.